# Error: "ENOENT, no such file or directory" when installing pdf417 phonegap plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to use pdf417 in my phoneGap cordova project . 
But I faced a problem in installing it via cordova plugin tool.

I use the following command :

```
$cordova plugin add https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-phonegap.git
```

which leads to the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/var/folders/24/qhdky3f14dd93y227kw3clwc0000gn/T/git/1432545791230/plugin.xml'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:502:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:354:15)
at Object.module.exports.parseElementtreeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/util/xml-helpers.js:118:27)
at new PluginInfo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/PluginInfo.js:320:37)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/plugins.js:45:30
at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
```

I searched about this result and I found that maybe the `plugin.xml` does not exist in the main directory and is located in a subdirectory.

I do not know if this assumption is true or not.

If it is true how can I solve it ?

Comment: "maybe the plugin.xmlis not exist in the main dir and it located in sub one" - did you check that?

Comment: it's really in subdirectory not in main dir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer  
before adding the pdf417 plugin you should remove the cordova platform if exist , and download the pdf417 plugin "the zip file" ,extract it ,then by command

```
cd your_project_dir
cordova plugin add ../pdf417-phonegap-master/Pdf417
cordova platform add android/ios
```

this solve the problem for me

Comment: When I add the pluglin before the platform with --link, I lose the linking to the local files for some reason.